# Non-Linear Ordinary Differential Equation - Lienard Equation

Tags: differential-equations

While trying to solve a circuit equation, I stumbled onto a type of Lienard Equation. But, I am unable to solve this analytically.

```
x'' + a(x-1)x' + x = V  -------------------------  (1)
```

where dash(') represent differentiation w.r.t time(t).

The following substitution y =x-V and w(y) = y', it gets converted into first order equation

```
w*w' + a(y+V-1)w + y = 0;  ----------------------  (2)
```

here dash(') represent differentiation w.r.t y.

if I substitute `z = (int)(-a*(y+V-1)`, (int) represent integration. The equation gets converted into Abel equation of second kind.

```
w*w' - w = f(z).  --------------------   (3)
```

differentiation w.r.t z.

it get complicated and complicated.

Can someone help in solving the equation (1). in some other method or proceeding with the method, I started. ANy help will be extremely appreciated

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming. Mathematical questions of this level can get answers on math.SE. Add some attempt to solve this via some program if this is to stay on-topic here.